# How to randomly update a selected element in a 2D array?

Tags: java, arrays

So I am trying to assign a variable called lesserMonster, which is assigned to 1. I have a four-by-four array that prints all 0 and I want my code to randomly select one of the 0 in the four-by-four and replace it with the lesserMonster varible. Any clues?

So this method generates the four-by-four array:

```
public static void setup(int dungeon[][]){
        int lesserMonster = 2;
        int drangon = 1;
        //makes the dungeon.
        for(int i = 0; i < dungeon.length; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < dungeon[i].length; j++){
                dungeon[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }
        pDungeon(dungeon);
    }
```

and the pDungeon array prints it:

```
public static void pDungeon(int dungeon[][]){
        for(int i = 0; i < dungeon.length; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < dungeon.length; j++){
                System.out.print(dungeon[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
```

Comment: As a starter, check out Math.random and think about how you could pick a single X and y coordinate that fits in your dungeon. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

This is a javascript solution, but should give you the basic idea;

```
const arrayRows = 4;
const arrayCols = 4;

const row = Math.floor(Math.random() * arrayRows);
const col = Math.floor(Math.random() * arrayCols);

dungeon[col][row] = lesserMonster;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can randomly select a row and a column to place your monster, for example:

```java
int row = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(dungeon.length);
int column = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(dungeon[row].length);
dungeon[row][column] = lesserMonster;
```

Also, I would suggest to make `lesserMonster` and `dragon` static final fields of your class so you can access them from other methods. And in your pDungeon method it's better to use the same loop over `j` which you use in `setup` method:

```java
for (int j = 0; j < dungeon[i].length; j++)
```

Right now you have `j < dungeon.length` which assumes the dungeon has a square shape.